# Error When Kafka Sending Message to Spark Streaming

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am sending file to spark streaming using kafka and spark. Spark is a consumer. I am sending data as like this "cat ~/WISDM_ar_v1.1_raw.txt | bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test". Then it write to console ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>". Then when spark is working on data and if kafka finish to send message, spark stop because kafka stop earlier.

I am using Spark 2.4.0 and Kafka 2.1

push data to kafka producer

```
cat ~/WISDM_ar_v1.1_raw.txt | bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test"
```

start spark streaming with jar

```
./bin/spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.4.0,org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:3.10.0 --class org.apache.spark.spark_streaming_kafka_0_10_2.App /home/mustafa/eclipse-workspace/sparkJava.jar
```

sparkJava

```
        BasicConfigurator.configure();

        mongoClient = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress("localhost", 27017));
        db = mongoClient.getDatabase("people"); 
        collection  =  db.getCollection("persondetails");
        Document document = new Document();



        SparkConf conf=new SparkConf().setAppName("kafka-sandbox").setMaster("local[*]");
        JavaSparkContext sc=new JavaSparkContext(conf);
        JavaStreamingContext ssc=new JavaStreamingContext(sc,new Duration(1000l));
        Map<String, Object> kafkaParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        kafkaParams.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
        kafkaParams.put("key.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class);
        kafkaParams.put("value.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class);
        kafkaParams.put("auto.offset.reset", "latest");
        kafkaParams.put("enable.auto.commit", false);
        kafkaParams.put("auto.offset.reset", "latest");

        kafkaParams.put(org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG,"0");       

        Collection<String> topics = Arrays.asList("bigdata" );

        JavaInputDStream<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> stream =
          KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(
                  ssc,
            LocationStrategies.PreferBrokers(),
            ConsumerStrategies.Subscribe(topics, kafkaParams)

          );


        stream.foreachRDD((rdd -> {
            System.out.println("new rdd "+rdd.partitions().size());
            rdd.foreach(record -> {


                ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(record.value().split(",")));



                document.append("user", list.get(0))
                .append("activity", list.get(1))
                .append("timestamp", list.get(2))
                .append("x-acceleration", list.get(3))
                .append("y-accel", list.get(4))
                .append("z-accel", list.get(5).replace(";",""));


                collection.insertOne(document);
                document.clear();

            });
            }));



        ssc.start();
        ssc.awaitTermination();

        mongoClient.close();
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "streaming-job-executor-0" java.lang.Error: java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1155)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:998)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1304)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryAwait(Promise.scala:206)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:222)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:157)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitReady(ThreadUtils.scala:243)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:728)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2061)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2082)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2101)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2126)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(RDD.scala:927)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(RDD.scala:925)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.foreach(RDD.scala:925)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.foreach(JavaRDDLike.scala:351)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.foreach(JavaRDDLike.scala:45)
    at org.apache.spark.spark_streaming_kafka_0_10_2.App.lambda$main$74bb78aa$1(App.java:65)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStreamLike$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1.apply(JavaDStreamLike.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStreamLike$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1.apply(JavaDStreamLike.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:628)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:628)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:416)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.Job.run(Job.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(JobScheduler.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:257)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler.run(JobScheduler.scala:256)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    ... 2 more
2019-04-06 01:59:12 INFO  JobScheduler:54 - Stopped JobScheduler
73427 [Thread-1] INFO org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler  - Stopped JobScheduler
2019-04-06 01:59:12 INFO  ContextHandler:910 - Stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@124d02b2{/streaming,null,UNAVAILABLE,@Spark}
73431 [Thread-1] INFO org.spark_project.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler  - Stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@124d02b2{/streaming,null,UNAVAILABLE,@Spark}
```

I expect all datas send push to mongo but just get 310.000 data from file.

Comment: Rather that writing and maintaining your own Spark code. I might suggest a more commonly used solution of Kafka Connect. https://github.com/hpgrahsl/kafka-connect-mongodb

Answer (score 0):

You're using `kafkaParams.put("auto.offset.reset", "latest");`, which means that you have Spark reading from the end of the topic.

If you want Spark to read all the data currently in the topic that was produced, then you need to set that to be `"earliest"`

It's not clear what you mean by Kafka "stops earlier"... If Kafka process is actually stopping, then the issue isn't your Spark code

---

FWIW, there is no need to use `cat`, since Spark can read and parse CSV files itself. Therefore, using Kafka at all is not entirely necessary unless you have other consumers

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. When I read the file with java code it takes lines which have less parameter than 6 and error occurs. I fixed the code it works now.